# How do I remove the septic effluent pump

Tags: septic

I have an aerobic septic system. I need to remove the effluent pump that drives the sprinklers. It seems connected to the floor of the tank. After disconnecting the pipe union, I can rotate the stack of pump and vertical discharge pipe multiple turns in either direction, but can not raise it nor move it side-to-side to side.  Is there a locking system in some tanks to keep the pumps in place?   Thank you,

Comment: Can you see what the thing is doing when you try to move it, or what could be holding it down?

Comment: The pump body is definitely rotating with the pipe.  It seems to pivot in place. I can even tilt the stack somewhat while moving it in circular motion around the circumference of the riser opening.

Comment: I can see most of the pump but I can't see the bottom of the pump as there is about 4" of sludge and 4" of water still above the sludge.

Comment: Muck is a pretty good suction cup.

Comment: Good point. I think I will rig up something to put down there and jet away the sludge from the base and try then. I may not get too it until next Saturday now. I'll report back as soon as I try that. Thank you for your prompt inputs.